# How to prevent index from showing without language

Tags: php, laravel, localization, translation

How to Prevent

```
project_path/
```

from showing anything, 
and redirect to

```
project_path/en or project_path/fr
```

using Laravel,

I'm follwing this tutorial 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/example-on-how-to-use-multiple-locales-in-your-laravel-5-website

Comment: Can you try writing a redirect rule in Apache's .htaccess

Comment: Show the code you have (even if it is the result of following that tutorial).